# If you depressurize an aircraft at FL340, will the temperature inside fall to match the temperature outside?

Tags: cabin-pressure, temperature

Assuming you’d have an oxygen mask on before hand, and you depressurized the aircraft at FL340, would the inside and outside temperatures quickly become the same?

Comment: It depends on your definition of "quickly", and whether or not you continue pumping hot air, (albeit at significantly lower pressure) into the cabin.

Comment: For those who didn't know what FL340 was, it seems to mean an altitude of 34,000 feet (measured by air pressure): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_level

Comment: @BenCrowell Yes, that's exactly what it means. It's a [pressure altitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_altitude) of 34,000 feet.

Comment: Are you thinking about the worst greek air disaster?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helios_Airways_Flight_522

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This depends entirely on **how** you depressurized it.

Depressurizing the aircraft by fully opening the outflow valve will lower the temperature somewhat, but will not bring it to that outside.

The expansion process will be closest to [free (Joule) expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_expansion), which causes only small decrease in temperature, not an adiabatic one that corresponds to the atmospheric lapse rate. And while some energy will be lost through the air's initial expansion as it escapes, it will quickly be replaced by new warm air coming in through the packs ([cabin pressurization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabin_pressurization) and air conditioning system).

That air supply is quite reliable, as it's bled from engines at about $200\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ – it then needs to be air-conditioned so as not to roast the passengers. The packs will automatically maintain set temperature, putting less effort into cooling the air if the cabin gets too cold.

If you also disable the engines, so no new air can come in, the airplane will lose some heat. Still, in all other regards, the fuselage will remain a well-insulated vessel with some heat sources on the inside. Also, the less-dense air is much less effective at heat transfer, and has much less heat capacity, so it will get chilly, but the passengers aren't going to freeze to death or even get a frostbite.

The heat capacity of air at ambient pressure will be about $280\ \frac{\mathrm{J}}{\mathrm{m}^3\cdot\mathrm{K}}$. A 737 encloses about $200\ \mathrm{m}^3$, giving a total of $56\ \frac{\mathrm{kJ}}{\mathrm{K}}$. For comparison, the plane's passengers have a specific heat capacity of $3.5\ \frac{\mathrm{kJ}}{\mathrm{kg}\cdot\mathrm{K}}$, giving, for 120–160 of them, about $40\ \frac{\mathrm{MJ}}{\mathrm{K}}$. So a $\sim70\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ one-time drop in air temperature can technically match the outside, but it can only cool the passengers by at most $0.1\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$.

In practice, the cooling won't be instant, and it has to compete with heat exchange with the still-warm interior. Passenger bodies producing $12{-}18\ \mathrm{kW}$ of waste heat (at rest) will also restore cabin air temperature by $\sim1\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ every 4 seconds. The larger the hole, the lower the temperature minimum that will be reached. With a broken window, the effect of this one-time expansion heat loss will have been mostly undone before anyone notices it, amidst the chaos.

[Tearing the top of the fuselage off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aloha_Airlines_Flight_243), on the other hand, will most definitely let the passengers feel the cold outside. But it will be the powerful wind blowing **in**, not the air leaving the airplane, that will chill its interior.

Breaking a single window or making a lot of bullet holes (really a lot - it will take a crate of ammo to overcome the packs' air inflow) is about the same as fully opening the outflow valve. It will produce some cooling effect, but it will definitely **not** bring the interior to the outside temperature, as the cooling effect is one-time, and will be rapidly compensated for.

This kind of event has happened [a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Airlines_Flight_96) [few](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2018/apr/17/philadelphia-plane-emergency-southwest-landing-engine-explosion-latest) [times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Airways_Flight_5390) in aviation history. It has caused some fatalities – a person sitting right next to the broken window has been killed by the mechanical force of the escaping air. No one has been frozen to death, not even in the [Aloha Flight 243](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aloha_Airlines_Flight_243), which represents about the worst possible case for depressurization (which still leaves survivors and not just a debris field).

Comment: @Bianfable The plane was turned into a landaulet, with winds free to ravage the interior, and getting scooped up by the remaining part of the fuselage. It's as bad as it gets while still allowing the plane to land (thanks to the cockpit staying enclosed).

Comment: What's a "pack(s)"? And can those, or any other part of a plane's HVAC system be run on the APU? And can the system provide heat with the engines off?

Comment: @Mazura Integrated or packaged aircon system. And from the diagrams [here](https://www.avsoft.com/product/airbus-a320-system-diagrams/), it looks like yes, the APU can supply them, though likely not enough for full performance.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhereSupportsMonica, if the APU is running, it can feed the packs, but most APUs won't run at cruise altitude.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the cabin is pressurized to a pressure equivalent of that at 8000ft, the initial pressure is on board is $P_1$ = 75262.4 Pa, and the temperature is T1 = 20ºC = 293.15K

At FL340, the outside pressure is $P_2$ = 24999 Pa.

Assuming we are talking about rapid decompression, there will be no significant heat transfer into or out of the gas during this process. We can thus approximate the temperature by using the laws of adiabatic cooling.

$P^{(1-\gamma)}T^\gamma = $ constant

Therefore:

$T_2 = \sqrt[\gamma]{\frac{P_1^{(1-\gamma)}T^\gamma}{P_2^{(1-\gamma)}}}$

With $\gamma$ = 1.4 for air.

Filling in the numbers will give $T_2$ = 213.96 K = -59.2ºC

The normal temperature at FL340 is about 222.8 K or -52.4ºC

After a rapid decompression, the temperature on board will thus be slightly below the outside temperature.

This sudden loss of temperature will cause moisture in the air to condensate into fog.

Since all the interior mass of the cabin is still at 20 degrees, the temperature will quickly rise again and the fog will disappear.

Here is a video of a rapid decompression in a pressure camber. 
Note the fog, and note how quickly the person passes out.

Comment: Excellent explanation that caters to all levels of knowledge!

Comment: Keep in mind that this is free expansion, as gas is not doing work against a piston. In free expansion, temperature change is minimal. A smaller hole is not completely free expansion, but much closer to it than it is to a heat engine cycle.

Comment: Note that the fog dissipates almost as quickly as it appeared though...

Comment: @JanHudec I guess that is because the fog is very good at catching IR radiation. Since the walls don"t cool down, there is plenty of heat transfer into the fog and since there is very little mass in the air, it warms up very quickly again.

Comment: @Therac Rapid decompression in an aircraft is no free expansion, there is no vacuum outside. Instead the outside air has quite some pressure and air inside the aircraft does the work of pushing that away.

Comment: The part I noticed in that video was how much difficulty the guy had getting his mask on. He knew it was coming. He had the calm reassurance of someone standing right there already fitted with O2 who he knew would step in to help him and he couldn't get the strap over his head. It took the helper several tries, too, while the test subject started to lose consciousness. Pretty scary! People, put your own mask on before trying to help anyone else, lest you join the dead!

Comment: @DeltaLima, it isn't. IR cameras are used to see through fog.

Answer (score 5):

More or less...

For gamma = 1,4, an adiabatic expansion from 1013 hPa to 226 hPa will cause an initial temperature of 20ºC = 273K to drop to 191 K.

The Standard Atmosphere temperature for that altitude is approx. that...

Comment: Are you sure the expansion would be isentropic?

Comment: @xxavier, Are you saying that the standard atmospheric temperature at FL340 is +20C?  If not, would you please clarify?

Comment: @MichaelHall Pretty sure he is assuming the cabin temperature to be 20°C but forgot to add the 273.15K to make it 293.15K in the cabin at the start of the expansion.

Comment: Yeah, but he goes on to say "the standard... is approx that".  Meaning approximately equal.

Comment: @pericynthion the OP does not specify, so lacking further nuance it is the only meaningful assumption, since the opposite possibility from a thermodynamic perspective would be an isothermal process, would it not?

Comment: @MichaelHall I read that as 191K, which is indeed close to the ISA temperature at 12km.

Comment: This holds only if no new air is coming in from the packs and if the passengers and the airplane aren't producing any heat. The heat capacity of that low-pressure air is tiny.

Comment: OK, let's get the numbers and units of measure defined and accurate.  191 degrees kelvin, (presuming that is "K"?) is -82C or -115F.  This is not 20C, nor is it the standard atmospheric temperature at 34K feet which is roughly -50C or -60F.  Please expand and clarify this answer.

Comment: The expansion will most definitely be isochoric, **not** adiabatic. Adiabatic expansion happens in a sealed cylinder, when the gas is producing work by acting against resistance. Air expansion from a tear in a container is going to produce [Joule expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_expansion), which results in no cooling with ideal gases and only a bit of cooling with real gases.

Comment: @MichaelHall ok, to straighten it out, it's either degrees Celsius or Kelvins (which are not degrees), and what I believe the answer says is, air with $\gamma$=1.4 at 273K would cool to 191K during an adiabatic expansion, which is rather close to the 220K at 34kft ISA. Therac: oh, yeah, that one... I had a feeling I was forgetting something.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I did not convert 220 Kelvin so 191 is closer than I realized.  Having said that, pilots and most lay people don't deal with Kelvin.  I am reasonably intelligent and can appreciate scientific explanations, but answers should be tailored to a wider audience.  And I don't know what "gamma = 1,4" means either...  For that reason I am downvoting for now.

Comment: @Therac, Joule expansion assumes expansion into a vacuum, so no work is done by the gas. That is not the case here; the pressure at FL340 is lower than at sea level, but nowhere near vacuum.

Comment: @DeltaLima True. Thinking about it, this is neither the Joule process nor isentropic expansion. The case is actually a lot more complex than just using one linear formula, it's not any one simply-modeled process. The truth will be somewhere in between, the air will cool somewhat, but it's expanding against very little resistance, just equalizing the pressure on two sides of a wall.

Comment: The air in the cabin is *not* 1013 hPa, it is only 750 hPa.

Comment: @Therac: the air remaining inside the fuselage is doing work pushing air through the hole.  The air going *through* the hole is expanding into much lower pressure.  Analogy: a CO2 fire extinguisher blows cold CO2 that expanded from a much higher pressure.  The tank of the extinguisher also cools off some, I think?  I also considered a propane tank for a BBQ or camp stove, but I think in that case some of the cooling is from liquid propane boiling to maintain constant vapour pressure in the tank so it's not a good analogy.  Heat of vaporization is different from ideal or real gas expansion.